# How to use/call gyros in the application for Android

Tags: java, android, motorola, motorola-droid, xoom

I am working on  MOTOROLA XOOM for app. development. I want to use gyros sensor in my application. If someone can help me out to call gyros in my program.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Use `SensorManager`, to register a `SensorEventListener` for the default `Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE` sensor. Your `SensorEventListener` will receive `SensorEvent` objects in `onSensorChanged()`. There, you can read the angular speed around the X/Y/Z axes from the `SensorEvent`. Details of the angular speed data can be found in [the documentation for `SensorEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).